# For-Loop in For-Loop appears to skip iterations (r)

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to run a for loop in a for loop, however it doesn't behave in the way I expect. I would expect it to cycle through the elements in the 'inner' loop, and then swap to the next element in the 'outer' loop and repeat.

e.g.

```
Letters = c('AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD')

for(i in 1:length(Letters)) {

  LetDup <- Letters

  for(i in 1:length(LetDup)) {

    Combined <- paste0(Letters[i], ' vs ', LetDup[i])

    print(Combined)

  }
}
```

I was expecting to get

```
AA vs AA
AA vs BB
AA vs CC
AA vs DD
BB vs AA 
BB vs BB
.....
```

How do I indicate that this is what I would like, and if someone could offer a simple explanation of what I've actually asked it to do, that would help as well.

Comment: Try `do.call(paste, c(expand.grid(Letters, Letters), sep= " vs "))`

Comment: Also just a few notes. You don't need to make LetDup even if you take the looping approach. You do need to use a different index for the two loops though. Currently you use i to index both loops.

Comment: By using the same variable, i, in both loops, you will always be using the 2nd/inner i's value.  R can't tell when you want the outer vs inner i.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using loops, take @Dason's comment and do the following:

```
for(i in 1:length(Letters)) {
  for(j in 1:length(Letters)) {
    Combined <- paste0(Letters[i], ' vs ', Letters[j])
    print(Combined)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can either use `expand.grid` or `CJ` (from `data.table`) and then do a `paste`

```
library(data.table)
CJ(Letters, Letters)[, paste(V1, 'vs', V2)]
```